# Is there a chapter on alcoholic drinks in Shaybani's Kitaab al Aathaar?

Tags: fiqh, hanafi, alcohol

I was reading a [research paper](http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/136485/1/Islam_Alcohol_and_Identity_Towards_a_Cri.pdf) on Imam Abu Hanifa's views on alcohol, and it mentioned a few hadiths in **باب الأشربة أنْبِذة و الشرب قائما وما يكره في الشراب (Chapter on Al-
coholic Beverages and Wines and Drinking Standing and Rebukable [Mannerisms] Concern-
ing Drinking)** of his student al Shaybani's **Kitab al aathaar**. I have located the book [online](https://www.waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=2659), but can't seem to find that chapter. Can someone guide me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here:

- [Stream](https://archive.org/details/athar_alshibany/page/n710/mode/2up)
- [Pdf (page 699)](https://ia802706.us.archive.org/22/items/athar_alshibany/athar_alshibany.pdf#page=710)

Comment: May I ask why I wasn't able to locate this [here](https://www.waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=2659)? Is that a different version of the book?

Comment: @Daud You should compare the two. My guess is that yours is incomplete, and there are supposed to be more volumes that have not been uploaded.